# VMWare Fusion samba share very slow in a CentOS on a Yosemite host

Tags: centos, samba, osx-yosemite

I bought a new iMac, installed the latest version of VMWare, copied over all my data, including a CentOS 6.5 vm, and when I connect to it via samba, it's **absolutely insanely slow**. I mean like 20-60 seconds just to list a directory using ls -al. The thing is, mounting the share is instant/crazy fast. Its only when I try to access data in the directory (or create new folders) where it's slow.

I noticed that the file icons are also loading super slow, for example here's a screenshot:

[image: file icons]

After working with it more, I noticed I'm also seeing it in directories that don't even have image files, so unchecking "Show icon preview" in the view options didn't seem to help any.

Just noticed doing `ls -al` in a sub-directory was fast, but I have the same sub-dir open in Finder and it's just the spinner spinning:

[image: subdirectory]

Took about 20 seconds to load. Not that it probably matters but my iMac is on an ethernet connection. FileVault is disabled and the Firewall is disabled.

Getting info on a file that is listed but does not yet have an icon displayed seems to cause the slowness too. Just sits there at "Fetching..." - this one has been spinning for a good 30 seconds or so:

[image: More Info]

Working with samba shares in Yosemite was really fast on my old computer, no idea what changed.

Tried disabling spotlight: http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/10/disable-or-enable-spotlight-in-mac-os-x-lion/ - no luck.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need:

`protocol = SMB2`

in smb.conf or it is just completely unusable. :(